# Is there any particular reason the position of the public/private keywords change depending on whether it's a function or variable?

Tags: solidity

I fear it will be difficult for me to remember if this quirk of the language is arbitrary...

Comment: You have nothing to fear from. The compiler will not let you get away with placing this keyword in the wrong place. So in the worst case, you'll get compilation errors but not runtime errors for this type of mistake (and as you are well aware of - compilation errors are good, while runtime errors are bad).

Comment: Is there no rationale behind this design choice?

Comment: Not everything is well thought of when a new language-standard is born. Take C for example - `char`, `short`, `long`, `int`, `short int`, `long int`, `long long` and `long long int` are all valid integer types, yet only one of them is named properly.

Comment: Wait, it gets worse - `float` and `double` are valid rational types, yet neither one of them is named properly.

Comment: Wait, it gets even worse - `struct` and `union` - you can specify their name at the beginning of the declaration or at the end of the declaration or both. Well, the one on the beginning is not exactly a name, but more like a "tag" or something like that, and it's not really used for anything.

Comment: Have you had enough, or would you care to hear about the syntax for function pointers?